# How to exclude items from a drop down based on another drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three identical drop downs.  I want to select a value from drop1 and have that value excluded from drop2.  Then the selections in drop3 should exclude 1 & 2.  Any ideas?

```
<select name="drop1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="drop2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="drop3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how comfortable you are with PHP, or AJAX you have two solutions. 
If you are more comfortable with PHP you could have a user submit the data from one select form and then using if statements like

```
if $value != '1'{ 
echo '<option value="1">1</option>'; 
}
```

and do that for each field in the second form; then replicate that for the third form.

The smoother looking solution would be using AJAX to use a listener to see when a user clicks a field a java value is set as that field and using a similar "if then show" method on the java-script variable to hide the fields that contain that value in the other forms.

Also one of the easiest solutions would be allowing multiple-selections (Assuming you are ok with the look of using one form & the values between the forms are the same like the example you gave above)... That example being:

```
<select id="my_num" name="my_num" size="5" multiple="multiple" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event and remove selected elements from the dom

```
$('select[name=drop1]').change(function() {
    var drop2 = $('select[name=drop2]').empty().hide();
    var exclude = $(this).val();
    var size = $(this).children().length;
    for (var i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        if (i != exclude) {
           drop2.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }
    }
});
```

if you have more complex example and you need value based explude you can create a clone.

```
var clone = $('select[name=drop2]').clone();
$('select[name=drop1]').change(function() {
    var copy = clone.clone();
    copy.find('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove().end();
    $('select[name=drop2]').replaceWith(copy);
});
```